# How to export a video in expecific ratio

Tags: premiere

When exporting this video, I get all the content inside the red box. But, I want the content inside green box.

How can I do it in Adobe Premiere?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your sequence settings **Sequence>Settings** and change the resolution to match the size of the rectangle you want.

[image: seq settings]

When you want to export the media, in the export settings click the button in the video tab that says **Match Source**, this will set the export resolution to match your timeline. Some codecs (e.g. avid DNxHD) will not allow non-standard resolutions, and most will only allow even numbers of pixels in either dimension (e.g. h.264) so you may have to change codec.

[image]